# Problem with SQL group by and summing totals with a calculated column and sub query

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery

I have this query that is working but I'm having trouble with the next step.  It calls three different tables and returns a column of account numbers and a cost.  I would like to sum the cost but grouped by account numbers.  If I were starting out with just a two column table this is trivial.  I'm running into issues doing it with a sub query for various reasons.  Any input is apprecieated.

```
select top 100 tblPart.Account,(tblPartLocation.OnHand * tblPart.CostAverage)
as TotalCost 
from tblPartLocation
join tblPart on tblPart.Part = tblPartLocation.Part

Account  Cost
accnt1   3.56  
accnt1   4.78 
annct2   5.00
accnt1   1.23
accnt4   0.01
accnt5   1.01
accnt3   7.45
```

The expected output is

```
Account  Cost
accnt1   9.57  
accnt2   5.00 
annct3   7.45
accnt4   0.01
accnt5   1.01
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Do you still want it to return first 100 rows?

Comment: No I just had that because there are 6k records.  I will remove top.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use sql `sum()` function then aggregate by **Account**.

```
select tblPart.Account, sum(tblPartLocation.OnHand * tblPart.CostAverage) as TotalCost 
from tblPartLocation
join tblPart on tblPart.Part = tblPartLocation.Part
group by tblPart.Account
```

Comment: Wow, I just tried that is SSMS.  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this using [SUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
select Account, sum(TotalCost) as TotalCost from (
    select tblPart.Account, (tblPartLocation.OnHand * tblPart.CostAverage) as TotalCost 
    from tblPartLocation
    join tblPart on tblPart.Part = tblPartLocation.Part
    ) as T1
group by Account
```